# Display Flex start and end React native

Tags: react-native, flexbox

So i have two components of button, i try to make the displaydirection into Row using flexDirection, here is my try and what it looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Animated,
  View,
  Text,
  Pressable,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';
import {IconClosedX} from '../../assets';
import {Button} from 'react-native-paper';
import {useCardAnimation} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {ScrollView, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');
const ModalsCC = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,

        marginTop: 300,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#ffff',
        borderRadius: 10,
      }}>
      <View
        style={{
          marginTop: 10,
        }}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            textTransform: 'capitalize',
          }}>
          Edit Keterangan
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 20,
          right: 20,
        }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={navigation.goBack}>
          <IconClosedX />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={Styles.viewContainer}>
        <ScrollView>
          <View>
            <Text>
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
              industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
              ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
              type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
              survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
              electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
              popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
              containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
              publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of
              Lorem Ipsum.
            </Text>
            <Text>
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
              industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
              ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
              type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
              survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
              electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
              popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
              containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
              publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of
              Lorem Ipsum.
            </Text>
            <Text>
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
              industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
              ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
              type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
              survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
              electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
              popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
              containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
              publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of
              Lorem Ipsum.
            </Text>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          justifyContent: 'space-between',
          backgroundColor: 'white',
        }}>
        <Button
          style={{margin: 10}}
          mode="contained"
          buttonColor="red"
          onPress={() => {
            navigation.goBack();
            console.log('test');
          }}>
          Close Modal
        </Button>

        <View>
          <Button
            style={{margin: 10}}
            mode="contained"
            onPress={() => {
              navigation.goBack();
              console.log('test');
            }}>
            Cancel Edit
          </Button>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default ModalsCC;

const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
  viewContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10,
    paddingTop: 0,
    paddingBottom: 0,
    marginTop: 20,
    height: height * 1.2,
    backgroundColor: '#E5E5E5',
  },
  viewAnimated: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  closeButton: {},
  text: {},
});
```

[image]

is there a way to make the button direction end to end, and not stick in the center, i try to search for answer but find nothing on the internet, any help on this or can someone pointed out where did i do wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add **width:'100%'** and delete extra **View** between button, this is the code

```
  <View
    style={{
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'space-between',
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      width:'100%'
    }}>
    <Button
      style={{ margin: 10 }}
      mode="contained"
      buttonColor="red"
      onPress={() => {
        navigation.goBack();
        console.log('test');
      }}>
      Close Modal
    </Button>

    <Button
      style={{ margin: 10 }}
      mode="contained"
      onPress={() => {
        navigation.goBack();
        console.log('test');
      }}>
      Cancel Edit
    </Button>
  </View>
```